# Reload PageViewController with new data

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, reload

I need to reload my PageViewController when the user navigates back from another view.

In my example, the user navigates to an edit view to add a city in my weather app. When the user navigates back from the edit view, I want to reload the PageViewContgroller so the view for the newly added city shows up when the user swipes to it. How do I best achieve that?

See this screen capture:

[image]

Below the code for the RootViewController. I appreciate any help!

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class RootViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
  
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

    @IBOutlet var UI: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var editView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print ("viewDidLoad")
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        
        configureViewControllers()
        
        self.editView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.editView.layer.cornerRadius = self.editView.frame.height / 5.0
        self.editView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print ("viewWillApear")
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        
        //update data
        //??

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if(segue.identifier == "Locations") {
            
            let destVC: TableViewController = segue.destination as! TableViewController;
            destVC.modelViewController = self.modelController;
            
        }
    }

    func configureViewControllers() {
        // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.

        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        self.pageViewController!.delegate = self
        
        let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
        let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
        
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })
        
        self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController
        
        self.addChild(self.pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(editView)

    }
    

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var modelController: ModelController {
        // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
        // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
        if _modelController == nil {
            _modelController = ModelController()
        }
        return _modelController!
    }

    var _modelController: ModelController? = nil

    // MARK: - UIPageViewController delegate methods

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationFor orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewController.SpineLocation {
        if (orientation == .portrait) || (orientation == .portraitUpsideDown) || (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) {
            // In portrait orientation or on iPhone: Set the spine position to "min" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain just one view controller. Setting the spine position to 'UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid' in landscape orientation sets the doubleSided property to true, so set it to false here.
            let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0]
            let viewControllers = [currentViewController]
            self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

            self.pageViewController!.isDoubleSided = false
            return .min
        }

        // In landscape orientation: Set set the spine location to "mid" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain two view controllers. If the current page is even, set it to contain the current and next view controllers; if it is odd, set the array to contain the previous and current view controllers.
        let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0] as! DataViewController
        var viewControllers: [UIViewController]

        let indexOfCurrentViewController = self.modelController.indexOfViewController(currentViewController)
        if (indexOfCurrentViewController == 0) || (indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) {
            let nextViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController)
            viewControllers = [currentViewController, nextViewController!]
        } else {
            let previousViewController = self.modelController.pageViewController(self.pageViewController!, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController)
            viewControllers = [previousViewController!, currentViewController]
        }
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {done in })

        return .mid
    }
}
```

ModelController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

/*
 A controller object that manages a simple model
 
 The controller serves as the data source for the page view controller; it therefore implements pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: and pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:.
 It also implements a custom method, viewControllerAtIndex: which is useful in the implementation of the data source methods, and in the initial configuration of the application.
 
 There is no need to actually create view controllers for each page in advance -- indeed doing so incurs unnecessary overhead. Given the data model, these methods create, configure, and return a new view controller on demand.
 */


class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    //var rootViewController = RootViewController()
    var cities = [""]
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")
    
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.cities = self.defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
        
        if self.cities == [""] || self.cities.count == 0  {
            self.cities = ["Current Location", "San Francisco", "New York"]
        }
    }
    
    func addCity(name:String) {
        self.cities.append(name)
        self.defaults.set(self.cities, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
    }


    func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int, storyboard: UIStoryboard) -> DataViewController? {
        // Return the data view controller for the given index.
        if (self.cities.count == 0) || (index >= self.cities.count) {
            return nil
        }

        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataViewController") as! DataViewController
        
        //get city name
        dataViewController.dataObject = self.cities[index]
        
        
        return dataViewController
    }
    
    
 
    func indexOfViewController(_ viewController: DataViewController) -> Int {
        // Return the index of the given data view controller.
        // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.
        return self.cities.firstIndex(of: viewController.dataObject) ?? NSNotFound
    }
    

    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }
        
        index -= 1
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = self.indexOfViewController(viewController as! DataViewController)
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }
        
        index += 1
        if index == self.cities.count {
            return nil
        }
        
        if index > 1 && currentCount > 2 {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        }
        
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index, storyboard: viewController.storyboard!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Show all relevant lines of code.

Comment: @ElTomato I don't even now what all relevant lines of code are, to be honest. Sorry, rookie here :(

Comment: You want to find out how you can reload your page view controller, but you don't show what you have in your page view controller?  Does that make sense?

Comment: @ElTomato apologies, I'm a newb as you can see :)

Perhaps it's easiest if I share all files via GitHub repo here: https://github.com/bjoern2000/FranzFahrenheit/tree/master/FranzFahrenheit

The background is that I used a template that Xcode provided (Multi-page app) that is not available anymore in newer Xcode version and I have no idea how the code in the template works. The issue I am trying to fix came up with iOS 13, without any code change on my side.

If you have any advise on how to address this I would highly appreciate it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's been a bit of a while since I used page view controller but I think you should call `setViewControllers` after your list of cities is updated. This should reload your page view controller and trigger the appropriate delegate methods.

Comment: Seems like it is related to the implementation of the `modelController`. Please reveal that.

Comment: @Kubee I am calling `configureViewControllers()` again on `viewWillAppear`, but it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. I read somewhere that a cached instance of my UIPageViewController is being used. How do I make it reload its data?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I added the code of `ModelController` to the original post

Comment: @Björn I don't see that. I see `addCity` does nothing after modifying the array. I think also that you're not using the same instance of `pageViewController` on both `ModelController` and `RootViewController`. but I find it confusing what you're doing with the model controller. Maybe you can simplify your code a bit and you might spot your issue by doing that?. For example, apple provides `lazy var` which can replace what you're doing with `_modelController`. Maybe you forgot to set pageViewController on the model with `self.pageViewController`?. I can list other small issues.

Answer (score 0):

Put your UI Related code in `viewWillAppear` method eg. `configureViewControllers()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jayesh! I tried that, but it does not solve the problem unfortunately. I confirmed that `viewWillAppear` is called correctly.

Comment: It seems that a cached instance of my UIPageViewController is used. How do I force it to refresh its data?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this function:

```
func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted: Bool)
```

in your page view controller delegate. When this method get called, you should update your view controller

Comment: Thank you @pastre! I added that function and it gets called everytime I swipe to a new page (left or right). What code do I need to execute in this function to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the data source “observable”? If you did that, the modification on page 2 should prompt the update on page 1.

You can also use RXSwift to accomplish the same, if you plan n using this design pattern more widely in your app - it becomes very handy.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Comment: Thanks Brian for the suggestion. How do I make a data source observable? Sorry, but I am on rookie level.

I think using RXSwift is way over my head unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use storyboards so it throws me off a bit. And I didn't use `UIPageViewController` for a while either. So i'll just list what I think **might** be the problem from memory. Don't consider this expert advice. So here it goes:

1. I think you'r using separate instances of `pageViewController` on `ModelController` and `RootViewController`, this might solve that issue:

```swift
private lazy var modelController: ModelController = {
    let modelController = ModelController()
    modelController.pageViewController = self.pageViewController
}()
```

And remove all that `_modelController: ModelController` stuff. Thats what `lazy` is for.

I would also make `pageViewController` on `ModelController` `weak`.

```swift
weak var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
```

you don't have a retain cycle without it but it wouldn't hurt.

2. You don't do anything after `func addCity(name:String)`. You know your code best but shouldn't you call `configureViewControllers()` after adding a city?. You will have to move this method to ModelController. But thats ok, it's got a reference to the same `pageViewController` so it works.
3. Why do you configure your `pageViewController` with only 1 VC in the beginning? Shouldn't you give it all the VCs for all the cities? But I'm not that sure about that one. So don't take my word for it.
4. I don't know if this is important but you are creating new VCs every time you call `viewControllerAtIndex`. I don't think thats right. I think you should create them once and store them. But I'm not certain about this. Even if you don't need this it will help with performance and with the UX as it remembers the user's scroll position when you swipe left and right.

Comment: Thank you @kubee, I'll try to work through all your suggestions!